# angular app with docker - production & development

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple AngularJS application. the backend can be treated like a service (external api), so no sever side is needed at all. I would like to run it on a docker, however, i'm not sure what is the best practice here.
what i'm expecting to achieve is the following:

1. the docker should be able to run everything i was doing locally with nodejs - using webpack/grunt/gulp without the need to install anything on my local machine + making sure every team member is working on the same version of basically everything.
2. the docker should be able to be deployed to production easily and run as lightly as possible (its just static content!)

the real issue is that as far as i understand, the dev docker should be based on nodejs with a mounted volume and everything.. however, the production docker should be super simple nginx server that serves static content. so i might end up with a 2 separate dockers that use the same code base. not sure if this is the right way to go..

can anyone shed some light over this topic? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas seems ok. I generally create a bash script(as for me it's flexible enough) to deploy different environments according to requirement(dev&prod).

Assumed created a bash script deployApp.sh

```
sh deployApp.sh `{dev or prod}`
```

So you can also create(or switch) Dockerfile on the fly according to your environment and build your app with this Dockerfile. So you can manage your prod environment requirements(only deploy to nginx with webpack's created bundles etc.) what you need respectively.

An example about creating deployApp.sh:

```
webpack `{if other required parameters here}`  #created bundle.js etc.

#After webpack operations , choose Dockerfile for prod or dev : 
#./prod/Dockerfile , ./dev/Dockerfile

#check if first parameter is prod or dev
docker build -f ./prod/Dockerfile  #this will build nginx based container 
#and copy needed files&folders
```

That is just an approach according to your idea, also i use like that approach. You just create that setup one time. Also you can apply another projects If it is suitable.

Comment: why do i actually need the bash file? so we got 2 dockerfiles - we can just use them accordingly. for example, use the dev one locally using a nice docker-composer and use the other one with jenkins (might have a different pre-made docker-compose as well). i could even say that the production files (dockerfile&docker-compose file) could be created on the fly by the build/deploy computer and the developers will never know about them. what do you think?

Comment: @BenYitzhaki I didn't use docker-compose yet. So If you know it's enough for that operations via docker-compose .yml file , of course you can use that way , bash scripting is not really a must in this situation.